# using regexp_substr inside a function that returns cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to make a function that parse a string and turn it into rows using regexp_substr but the string and the delimiter should be dynamic.

```
DECLARE   

  txt VARCHAR2(30)    := '10;20;30';
  delim varchar2(2) := ';';

BEGIN 
    open :c for 'SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('''||txt||''',''[^' || delim || ']+'',1,LEVEL) FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('''||txt||''',''[^' || delim || ']+'',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL';
END;
```

the code above works well however I don't know how to put it into a function, this is my function below but does not return any thing (probably has error.. am I missing something?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EPM_APPS.FN_PARSER (toParse IN VARCHAR, delim IN VARCHAR)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;     
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor FOR 
    'SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('''||toParse||''',''[^' || delim || ']+'',1,LEVEL) FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('''||toParse||''',''[^' || delim || ']+'',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL';
  --CLOSE my_cursor;
  RETURN my_cursor;
END FN_PARSER;
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a SQL Object type:**

```
create or replace type delimted_list as table of varchar2(4000);
/
```

**The function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_PARSER (toParse IN VARCHAR, delim IN VARCHAR)
  RETURN delimted_list
AS  
   l_delimted_list  delimted_list := delimted_list();
BEGIN
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (toParse,'[^'||delim||']+',1,LEVEL) 
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_delimted_list
  FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (toParse,'[^'||delim||']+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
  RETURN l_delimted_list;
END FN_PARSER;
/
```

**Usage:**

```
select * from TABLE(FN_PARSER('Mahesh,Vignesh',','));

COLUMN_VALUE                                                                 ------------------
Mahesh                                                                
Vignesh
```

Comment: Hi sir Maheswaran, this works great! Thank you :)
but sir could it have some modification like for example spaces are also included?
I mean when I put a string in functions let's say like this one:
`'Hello;world;Hi; ;there;'`
should have an output like this:
Hello
world
Hi
(blank cell here)
there
(blank cell here)

Comment: the result should also be in column (I just don't know how to show here).. thank you very much.